# dialogflow not working with php sdk

Tags: php, dialogflow-es

I made a test bot it is working with the web demo integration but when I try it out with PHP SDK it is not responding

Here is my code

```
<?php

require_once  './vendor/autoload.php';

use DialogFlow\Client;
use DialogFlow\Model\Query;
use DialogFlow\Method\QueryApi;

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $query = $_POST['message'];
    /*
    $postData = array('query' => $query, 'lang' => 'en', 'sessionId' => 123456789);
    $jsonData = json_encode($postData);

    $ch = curl_init('https://api.dialogflow.com/v1/query?v=20150910');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonData);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json', 'Authorization: Bearer 9ceec516365649148a3d2a721d51697a'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    echo $result;
    curl_close($ch);
    /*$result = $jsonData;
    echo $result;*/
    /*
    try {
    $client = new Client('9ceec516365649148a3d2a721d51697a');
    $queryApi = new QueryApi($client);

    $meaning = $queryApi->extractMeaning('Hello', [
        'sessionId' => '1234567890',
        'lang' => 'en',
    ]);
    $response = new Query($meaning);
    echo $response;
} catch (\Exception $error) {
    echo $error->getMessage();
}*/


try {
    $client = new Client('c657c6bdd91b4de5a86f2dc3f3e8cbd8');
    error_log(print_r($query, TRUE));
    $query = $client->get('query', [
        'query' => 'Hello',
    ]);
    error_log(print_r($query, TRUE));
    $response = json_decode((string) $query->getBody(), true);
    error_log(print_r($response, TRUE));
    echo $response;
} catch (\Exception $error) {
    echo $error->getMessage();
}
}
?>
```

I am receiving data to my file and WAMP logs no error ....
as you can see i have printed errors in the log only the first log is printed i.e the message i am receiving.
i am not getting any responses form dialog flow even dialog flow is not receiving any data from me i have checked in the training module. please help

Thanks for any help

Comment: Did you publish your bot?